# python class methods and inheritance

Tags: python, class, methods, multiple-inheritance

I would expect the following code to print 012345 but it prints 012012. Why? I would expect the calls to incr to be accessing the same variables since they are inherited from the same class but they are clearly different variables.

```
class a(object):
    var = 0
    @classmethod
    def incr(cls):
        print cls.var
        cls.var+=1

class b(a):
    def func(self):
        super(b,self).incr()

class c(a):
    def func(self):
        super(c,self).incr()


t = a()
t1 = b()
t2 = c()
t1.func()
t1.func()
t1.func()
t2.func()
t2.func()
t2.func()
```

Comment: It doesn't effect the unexpected behavior you're seeing, but I want to note that you don't need to be using `super` here in either of your subclasses. You can just call `self.incr()` instead. You only need to use `super` when you want to skip over an different version of the function (usually because you've overridden in in the current class).

Comment: You should switch to Python 3.6.  https://pythonclock.org/

Answer (score 7):

They are inherited from the same class, but the `cls` passed to the `classmethod` via super is the current class where the method was called from. `super` accesses the base class version of the method, but the `cls` for the call is the class where the *super* call was made.

This is one of the *subtle* differences between doing:

```
def func(self):
    super(c, self).incr() # same as a.__dict__['incr'].__get__(self, type(self))()
```

and:

```
def func(self):
    a.incr()
```

You can confirm this by printing the current `cls` in your `incr` method in both cases:

```
def incr(cls):
    print cls
    ...
```

You should never assume that all `super` does is make a method call bound to the parent class. It does a lot more.

Keep in mind that when the first augmented assignment `+=` is performed, the initial value of `var` is read from the base class (since at this point it does not exist in the dict of the subclasses). The updated value is however written to the subclass. Calling `super` from the second subclass repeats the same behavior of reading the initial `var` value from `a`.

Comment: You may want to be explicit about the fact that it's the `cls.var+=1` line that behaves oddly when `cls` is different. The first time it's run, it *reads* the inherited value of `var` (which is `0` in the example, but could have been some other value if `t.incr()` had been called), but it *writes* to the specific `cls` rather than to the base class. All subsequent calls use the subclass's value without ever seeing the base class.

Comment: @Blckknght I'll add a short note about that.

Answer (score 3):

There is a way to produce the sequence 012345. You have to make sure that the `var` of class `a` is increased in the `incr` method, even when it is called in the subclasses.
To achieve this, increment by `a.var += 1`, not by `cls.var += 1`.

As pointed out by the other answers, the `var` is also inherited to `b` and `c`.
By using `cls.var += 1` both subclasses increase their own `var` instead of `a`'s `var`.

```
class a:
    var = 0
    @classmethod
    def incr(cls):
        print(cls.var)
        a.var += 1

class b(a):
    def f(self):
        super().incr()

class c(a):
    def f(self):
        super().incr()

cb = b()
cc = c()
cb.incr()
cb.incr()
cb.incr()
cc.incr()
cc.incr()
cc.incr()

cb.incr()
cc.incr()
```

Produces:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

Answer (score 0):

Both class `b` and class `c` inherit from class `a` separately, and `var` is set to 0 each time.

One way to have class `c` to get the same value of `var` in class `a` as class `b` does, class `c` can inherit from class `b` like so:

```
class a(object):
    var = 0  
    @classmethod
    def incr(cls):
        print cls.var
        cls.var+=1

class b(a):
    def func(self):
        super(b,self).incr()

class c(b):
    def func(self):
        super(c,self).incr()


t = a()
t1 = b()
t2 = c()
t1.func()
t1.func() 
t1.func()
t2.func()
t2.func()
t2.func()`
```

Comment: That only gives the expected result if the first call to `t2.func()` comes after all the `t1.func()` calls. If you mixed them up, you wouldn't get the result you'd expect. And it's very misleading to say that "`var` is set to 0 each time". There's only one `var` when it's zero (the one in `a`). It's after the first `incr` call that whatever class it was made on gets a new `var` attribute with the value `1`.