# How to extend functions of another class automatically?

Tags: python

I have a class `A` with dozen of functions. Now I want to extend those functions in class `B` but apply to a list of `A`. See the example below.

```
class A:
  def __init__(self):
      # initiate self.data

  def func1(self, *args, **kargs):
      # do things with self.data
  
  # there are a lot more functions like func1

class B:
  def __init__(self, n):
      self.list_of_A = [A() for i in range n]

  def func1(self, *args, **kargs):
      # do something here

      for a in self.list_of_A:
          a.func1(*args, **kargs)

      # do something here
```

The requirements are:

1. Because `A` has a lot of functions and it is impractical to rewrite all of them in `B`, I would like to have `B.func1` to be generated automatically (e.g. through some wrapper function mechanism).
2. `B.func1` can have the same docstring as `A.func1`.

Can someones suggest me how to do this?
Thanks!

Comment: how about the use of `super` in class inheritance? [post1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277367/how-does-pythons-super-work-with-multiple-inheritance) or [more recent post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45898310/python-class-methods-and-inheritance)

Comment: Your questions are getting closed because your descriptions are totally unclear. You are using terminology incorrectly. There *is no inheritance here*. Inheritance is a relationship between classes. Another example, "a set of". There are no sets here. You have a list. This may all sound nitpicky, but when you use standard terminology in a non-standard way, it makes communication difficult.

Comment: thanks. updated the description to make it clearer.

Comment: @martineau I think you closed this question but the answer that you pointed out does not solve this problem. Specifically, in this case, I don't have access to `A` class so I cannot wrap it. Also even if I do so, it still does not solve the problem stated in this ticket. Pls help open this. Thanks.

Comment: I don't really agree but will vote to reopen your question.

Comment: I now regret reopening your question, because it really **is** a duplicate of [How to wrap every method of a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11349183/how-to-wrap-every-method-of-a-class?noredirect=1&lq=1) as [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69184616/355230) below illustrates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways you could approach this. Here's *one* approach that I would hesitate to use because it highly couples both of these classes, but I'm showing it to you because it is an example of generating methods dynamically:

```
class B:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.list_of_A = [A() for i in range(n)]

     
    def _apply_a_method(self, method_name, *args, **kargs):
        # do something here

        for a in self.list_of_A:
            getattr(a, method_name)(*args, **kargs)
        
        # do something here
   
    @classmethod
    def build_api(cls, method_names):
        def _make_wrapper(method_name):
            def _wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
                return self._apply_a_method(method_name, *args, **kwargs)
            return _wrapper

        for method_name in method_names:
            setattr(cls, method_name, _make_wrapper(method_name))


B.build_api(["func1", "func2", "func3"]) # choose the functions you want
```

Note, this has *nothing to do with inheritance*. Inheritance is something that happens when you *subclass* from another class. That isn't what you are doing here. You are basically asking "how do I dynamically wrap various methods from class A into methods in class B".

Comment: Hah, this is very interesting. I will try this out. Thanks.

Comment: The issue I ran into with this code is that the returned class methods are `None` because by the time we run `B.build_api` the `list_of_A` is still undefined.

Comment: @Icb no, I just forgot a `return _wrapper` see the edit

Comment: It works. Much appreciated. Any suggestion on how to copy the function signature too i.e. `B.func1` can have the same signature as `A.func1`.

Comment: You can use `functools.wraps`

Comment: juanpa.arrivillaga, can you recommend a way to also make B have same properties as A. The current solution make everything become a function.

Comment: I found the way. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's proof that not only is your question a duplicate like I said it was of that [other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11349183/how-to-wrap-every-method-of-a-class), but also that it indeed *does* solve the problem.

A [metaclass](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-metaclass) approach is totally fitting because the essence of what you want to do is create new classes, and the instances of a metaclass are classes. The fact that these class instance are based on an existing ones means that it can be done "extending" or "wrapping" the methods of the existing one is an additional detail which making the *answer* to the duplicate question that much more suitable.

Also note that this technique is more generic and "automatic" than @juanpa.arrivillaga's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69169910/355230) in the sense that you don't have list the methods you want (since it does them all). And that it doesn't require changing class `A` as you claimed in a comment — although I did change it from what's in your question in order to have something more suitable for development and testing proposes.

Also note that the classes created *are* subclasses of the the base class, `A` in the example code, in terms of inheritance (not the metaclass).

```
from functools import wraps
from types import FunctionType


def wrapper(method):
    @wraps(method)
    def wrapped(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for instance in self.base_instances:
            method(instance, *args, **kwargs)

    return wrapped


class MyMetaClass(type):
    def __new__(meta, classname, bases, classdict):
        assert len(bases) == 1, 'A single base class is required'

        # Define an `__init__()` method.
        Base = bases[0]
        def __init__(self, n):
            self.base_instances = [Base() for _ in range(n)]

        # Create methods by wrapping those of base class.
        new_classdict = {key: wrapper(value) if isinstance(value, FunctionType) else value
                            for key, value in vars(Base).items()
                                if isinstance(value, FunctionType)}
        new_classdict['__init__'] = __init__  # Replace.

        # Construct the class using new class dictionary.
        return type.__new__(meta, classname, bases, new_classdict)

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = list(range(1, 5))  # Initialize self.data

    def func1(self, *args, **kargs):
        print(', '.join(str(i) for i in self.data))  # Do things with self.data

    def func2(self, *args, **kargs):
        print(f'sum: {sum(self.data)}')  # Do things with self.data

    # There are lots more functions like func1 & 2
    ...

class B(A, metaclass=MyMetaClass):
    pass

b = B(3)
b.func1()
b.func2()
```